# What is wrong with my sockets code?

Tags: objective-c, c, sockets

I'm working on an iOS version of my Android application which constantly sends some binary data to server over regular TCP connection. And while Java code works fine, my code in plain C doesn't - the connection breaks after the first bunch of data is sent to server. I managed to reimplement Java solution using CFNetwork framework, however my C code is still a problem...

C code (error checking and uninteresting code is removed):

```
mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
//...        
connect(mSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
int keepalive = 1;  
int res = setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&keepalive, 
                          sizeof(int));

int set = 1;
setsockopt(mSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&set, sizeof(int));

unsigned char buffer* = //...;
int ret = send(mSocket, buffer, bufferLen, 0);  //handshake with server, runs fine

while(/*there is new data*/) {
       buffer = new_data(); //some fake method
       ret = send(mSocket, buffer, bufferLen, 0); //On the second iteration 
                                                  //write returns -1
}
```

However, this Objective-C code based on CFNetwork works just fine...

Objective-C code:

```
 CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                                   host, 
                                   port, 
                                   &readStream, 
                                   &writeStream);
 CFWriteStreamOpen(mServerWriteStream);

 while(/*there is new data*/) {
     NSData* data = //....
     int wroteBytes = CFWriteStreamWrite(mServerWriteStream, [data bytes], [data length]);
 }
```

So I'm puzzled with what am I doing wrong in C code and will appreciate any hints

Thank you

Comment: What happens on the server side? Could it be that the server receives invalid data and closes the connection? Whats the return value of `send` in the first iteration? Is it equal to `bufferLen`? Is `bufferLen` the allocated size of the buffer or the size of the current message?

Comment: @Codo Server is third-party, can't say what is wrong at its side. And yes, on first iteration send returns value equal to bufferLen. bufferLen variable gets updated to indicate the value of each message

Comment: Please check `errno` to figure out the specific error code when `send` returns -1.

Comment: Errno equals to 2 which is ENOENT 2/* No such file or directory */ on my system. The fact is I added code to ignore EPIPE signal in my program, otherwise I would receive this signal on the second iteration

Comment: Most likely the server side has closed the connection (possibly because it couldn't successfully process the data sent in the first iteration).

Comment: Yep, that's most probably the case. However, what I can't understand is why the very same data is being processed without any errors if sent via CFWriteStreamWrite.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending exactly the same data in both cases? The error indicates otherwise.

Comment: Can't say I'm 100% sure, will try to check

Answer (score 2):

If you need a regular TCP connection you need to create the socket with such protocol. Instead of:

```
mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

You should create it as:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

On my system IPPROTO_TCP is defined as 6 and not 0. I suspect you have something similar.

Comment: +1 for spotting this, however the problem is still present, second call in loop returns -1

Comment: you can add ``if(ret == -1) perror("Send failed");`` and check what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

The setsockopt() has to execute before connect() or it is ignored.